# How to prove if 2 matrices have the same characteristic polynomial and are diagonalizable, they are similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand how to prove the other way around, where if two matrices are similar they have the same characterstic polynomial. But I don't think the reverse is true. I have the extra diagonalizable information, how do I use it to complete the proof.

Comment: If they are diagonalizable, you may as well view them as diagonal.

Comment: The converse is not true as you suggested. If a matrix is diagonalizeable it is similar to a diagonal matrix so there exist some $A$ such that $ADA^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal and note that $(ADA^{-1})^n=AD^nA^{-1}$ so polynomial expressions can be simplified easily for diagonalizable matrices. See if you can piece it together from there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this might work.

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ be your two matrices. Them beng diagonizable means that there exist invertible $X,Y \in \mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ such that $A = X^{-1}D_AX$ and $B = Y^{-1}D_BY$ where $D_A, D_B$ are diagonal, with respective eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ on the diagonal. But since $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues (they have the same characteristic polynomial), one can choose make it so that $D_A = D_B =: D$.

The rest is simple, because $$ A = X^{-1}DX = X^{-1}YBY^{-1}X = (Y^{-1}X)^{-1}B(Y^{-1}X),$$
i.e. $A$ and $B$ are similar.